# How to activate the dark mode in react native app when android theme set to dark mode?

Tags: android, react-native, android-dark-theme

I am developing a react native app which supports dark theme.

I used react navigation and created custom theme using React context. Now I can toggle between dark mode and light mode using a button. But I want to use the android theme (eg: dark mode) when opening the app. Which means if dark mode is enabled in the android, my app want to have dark mode enabled when opening the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`react-native-appearance`](https://github.com/expo/react-native-appearance):

```
import { AppearanceProvider, Appearance } from 'react-native-appearance';

export default () => (
  <AppearanceProvider>
    <App />
  </AppearanceProvider>
);

let colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme();

let subscription = Appearance.addChangeListener(({ colorScheme }) => {
  // do something with color scheme
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Facebook is still working on adding appearance support:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/63fa3f21c5ab308def450bffb22054241a8842ef

Until then, I'd recommend to use something like: https://github.com/expo/react-native-appearance

You can then retrieve the appearance settings of the device and load the appropriate stylesheets, with perhaps a fallback for non-dark mode or devices not supporting it.